# Fonts names in the Combobox List XAML c#

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, font-family

I'm designing a list of Fonts, where I refer to Fonts.SystemFontFamilies, but also I want to include 3 custom fonts that exist in my MyDllProject project. First I add the SystemFontFamilies, and works good, then I add my custom fonts (Roboto, Abstractus and OpenSans) and these add them well to the list, but it gives me the prefix **./#**. So, I would like to find a way to show the names of the font just like Abstractus, Roboto and Open Sans without nothing else.

The code of the comboBox is

```
if( _cmbFontFamilies != null )
      {
            _cmbFontFamilies.ItemsSource = FontUtilities.Families.OrderBy( fontFamily => fontFamily.Source );

      }
```

and the code for FontUtilities is

```
  internal class FontUtilities
  {
    internal static IEnumerable<FontFamily> Families
    {
      get
      {
      foreach ( FontFamily font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
      {
          yield return font;
      } 
      foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new 
          Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyDllProject ;Component/Resources/")))
       {
          yield return fontFamily;
       }   
      }
    }    
  }
```

The result that I have.
[image]

Comment: Could you share xaml code with ComboboxList?

Comment: Sorry, edited, now the code is more clear

Comment: Do you need to only display font names or do you use selected font family in your application for something else?

Comment: Yes, it's the same function for change the Font Family. So, is not enough to change the name, the Source must be in the SelectedValuePath and the Name in the DisplayValuePath, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each resulting `FontFamily` object returned by `Fonts.GetFontFamilies` has a friendly name of the form `"./#Family Name"`. This friendly name sets a `Source` property of `FontFamily` and the value of `Source` property is returned by `FontFamily.ToString()` method.

I would create a custom class `FontName`

```
public class FontName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

and return a collection of `FontName` by `FontUtilities.Families`. When loading custom fonts remove prefix `"./#"`

```
internal class FontUtilities
{
    internal static IEnumerable<FontName> Families
    {
        get
        {
            foreach ( FontFamily font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
            {
                yield return new FontName { Name = font.Source, Source = font.Source };
            } 
            foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new 
          Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyDllProject ;Component/Resources/")))
            {
              yield return new FontName { Name = fontFamily.Source.Replace("./#", string.Empty), Source = fontFamily.Source };
            }   
        }
    }    
}


if( _cmbFontFamilies != null )
{
    _cmbFontFamilies.SelectedValuePath = "Source";
    _cmbFontFamilies.DisplayValuePath = "Name";
    _cmbFontFamilies.ItemsSource = FontUtilities.Families.OrderBy( fontFamily => fontFamily.Source );

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same function for change the Font Family. So, is not enough to change the name, the Source must be in the SelectedValuePath and the Name in the DisplayValuePath, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: font.FamilyNames.Values.ElementAt(0).ToString(); return a string with the name of the Font, without the ***./#*** characters

Comment: @RobertoVargas Check the updated answer. I have added property Source to FontName class and set SelectedValuePath and DisplayValuePath.

Comment: Not works, I have to use that font in `ApplyPropertyValueToSelectedText( TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, (FontFamily)font);` and the FontName is not a FontFamily. Also the DisplayValuePath doesn't work, it's supposed that work's but itsn't.